# duplicate value for certain keys from array php

Tags: php

I Got an array like this:

```
array ( 0 => array ( 'AAAA' => 347, 'BBBB' => 321, 'START_DATE' => '2022-07-27', 'END_DATE' => '2022-07-27', 'CCCC' => 7, 'EXTRA' => '', ), 1 => array ( 'AAAA' => 348, 'BBBB' => 321, 'START_DATE' => '2022-07-27', 'END_DATE' => '2022-07-27', 'CCCC' => 7, 'EXTRA' => '', ), 2 => array ( 'AAAA' => 349, 'BBBB' => 321, 'START_DATE' => '2022-07-27', 'END_DATE' => '2022-07-27', 'CCCC' => 7, 'EXTRA' => '', ), 3 => array ( 'AAAA' => 350, 'BBBB' => 321, 'START_DATE' => '2022-07-27', 'END_DATE' => '2022-07-27', 'CCCC' => 7, 'EXTRA' => '', ), 4 => array ( 'AAAA' => 351, 'BBBB' => 321, 'START_DATE' => '2022-07-27', 'END_DATE' => '2022-07-27', 'CCCC' => 7, 'EXTRA' => '', ), 5 => array ( 'AAAA' => 352, 'BBBB' => 322, 'START_DATE' => '2022-07-27', 'END_DATE' => '2022-07-27', 'CCCC' => 2, 'EXTRA' => '', ), 6 => array ( 'AAAA' => 354, 'BBBB' => 323, 'START_DATE' => '2022-07-27', 'END_DATE' => '2022-07-27', 'CCCC' => 9, 'EXTRA' => '', ), 7 => array ( 'AAAA' => 355, 'BBBB' => 323, 'START_DATE' => '2022-07-27', 'END_DATE' => '2022-07-27', 'CCCC' => 9, 'EXTRA' => '', ), 8 => array ( 'AAAA' => 6, 'BBBB' => 1, 'START_DATE' => '2022-07-27', 'END_DATE' => '2022-07-27', 'CCCC' => 2, 'EXTRA' => '', ), 9 => array ( 'AAAA' => 6, 'BBBB' => 2, 'START_DATE' => '2022-07-27', 'END_DATE' => '2022-07-27', 'CCCC' => 2, 'EXTRA' => '', ), 10 => array ( 'AAAA' => 6, 'BBBB' => 3, 'START_DATE' => '2022-07-27', 'END_DATE' => '2022-07-27', 'CCCC' => 2, 'EXTRA' => '', ), 11 => array ( 'AAAA' => 6, 'BBBB' => 4, 'START_DATE' => '2022-07-27', 'END_DATE' => '2022-07-27', 'CCCC' => 2, 'EXTRA' => '', ), )
```

> ```
> Array
> (
>     [0] => Array
>         (
>             [AAAA] => 347
>             [BBBB] => 321
>             [START_DATE] => 2022-07-27
>             [END_DATE] => 2022-07-27
>             [CCCC] => 7
>             [EXTRA] => 
>         )
>
>     [1] => Array
>         (
>             [AAAA] => 348
>             [BBBB] => 321
>             [START_DATE] => 2022-07-27
>             [END_DATE] => 2022-07-27
>             [CCCC] => 7
>             [EXTRA] => 
>         )
>
>     [2] => Array
>         (
>             [AAAA] => 349
>             [BBBB] => 321
>             [START_DATE] => 2022-07-27
>             [END_DATE] => 2022-07-27
>             [CCCC] => 7
>             [EXTRA] => 
>         )
>
>     [3] => Array
>         (
>             [AAAA] => 350
>             [BBBB] => 321
>             [START_DATE] => 2022-07-27
>             [END_DATE] => 2022-07-27
>             [CCCC] => 7
>             [EXTRA] => 
>         )
>
>     [4] => Array
>         (
>             [AAAA] => 351
>             [BBBB] => 321
>             [START_DATE] => 2022-07-27
>             [END_DATE] => 2022-07-27
>             [CCCC] => 7
>             [EXTRA] => 
>         )
>
>     [5] => Array
>         (
>             [AAAA] => 352
>             [BBBB] => 322
>             [START_DATE] => 2022-07-27
>             [END_DATE] => 2022-07-27
>             [CCCC] => 2
>             [EXTRA] => 
>         )
>
>     [6] => Array
>         (
>             [AAAA] => 354
>             [BBBB] => 323
>             [START_DATE] => 2022-07-27
>             [END_DATE] => 2022-07-27
>             [CCCC] => 9
>             [EXTRA] => 
>         )
>
>     [7] => Array
>         (
>             [AAAA] => 355
>             [BBBB] => 323
>             [START_DATE] => 2022-07-27
>             [END_DATE] => 2022-07-27
>             [CCCC] => 9
>             [EXTRA] => 
>         )
>
>     [8] => Array
>         (
>             [AAAA] => 6
>             [BBBB] => 1
>             [START_DATE] => 2022-07-27
>             [END_DATE] => 2022-07-27
>             [CCCC] => 2
>             [EXTRA] => 
>         )
>
>     [9] => Array
>         (
>             [AAAA] => 6
>             [BBBB] => 2
>             [START_DATE] => 2022-07-27
>             [END_DATE] => 2022-07-27
>             [CCCC] => 2
>             [EXTRA] => 
>         )
>
>     [10] => Array
>         (
>             [AAAA] => 6
>             [BBBB] => 3
>             [START_DATE] => 2022-07-27
>             [END_DATE] => 2022-07-27
>             [CCCC] => 2
>             [EXTRA] => 
>         )
>
>     [11] => Array
>         (
>             [AAAA] => 6
>             [BBBB] => 4
>             [START_DATE] => 2022-07-27
>             [END_DATE] => 2022-07-27
>             [CCCC] => 2
>             [EXTRA] => 
>         )
> ```
>
> )

How can i find all the items that has the same value on keys : *BBBB, START_DATE, END_DATE,CCCC* ?

So the resutl will look like this :

> [0] => Array
> (
> [AAAA] => 347
> [BBBB] => 321
> [START_DATE] => 2022-07-27
> [END_DATE] => 2022-07-27
> [CCCC] => 7
> [EXTRA] =>
> )
>
> [1] => Array
> (
> [AAAA] => 348
> [BBBB] => 321
> [START_DATE] => 2022-07-27
> [END_DATE] => 2022-07-27
> [CCCC] => 7
> [EXTRA] =>
> )
>
> [2] => Array
> (
> [AAAA] => 349
> [BBBB] => 321
> [START_DATE] => 2022-07-27
> [END_DATE] => 2022-07-27
> [CCCC] => 7
> [EXTRA] =>
> )
>
> [3] => Array
> (
> [AAAA] => 350
> [BBBB] => 321
> [START_DATE] => 2022-07-27
> [END_DATE] => 2022-07-27
> [CCCC] => 7
> [EXTRA] =>
> )
>
> [4] => Array
> (
> [AAAA] => 351
> [BBBB] => 321
> [START_DATE] => 2022-07-27
> [END_DATE] => 2022-07-27
> [CCCC] => 7
> [EXTRA] =>
> )

---

> [6] => Array
> (
> [AAAA] => 354
> [BBBB] => 323
> [START_DATE] => 2022-07-27
> [END_DATE] => 2022-07-27
> [CCCC] => 9
> [EXTRA] =>
> )
>
> ```
> [7] => Array
>     (
>         [AAAA] => 355
>         [BBBB] => 323
>         [START_DATE] => 2022-07-27
>         [END_DATE] => 2022-07-27
>         [CCCC] => 9
>         [EXTRA] => 
>     )
> ```

Comment: use array_filter, or better yet use a database

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function to do it.

> ```
> public function getData($data, $key_search)
> {
>     $search_data = [];
>     foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
>         $value_search = '';
>         foreach ($key_search as $v_source) {
>             $value_search .= $value[$v_source];
>         }
>
>         $search_data[$value_search][] = $value;
>     }
>
>     $removed_single = [];
>     foreach ($search_data as $key => $value) {
>         if(count($value) > 1){
>             $removed_single[] = $value;
>         }
>     }
>
>     return $removed_single;
> }
> ```

From this data.

```
$data = array ( 0 => array ( 'AAAA' => 347, 'BBBB' => 321, 'START_DATE' => '2022-07-27', 'END_DATE' => '2022-07-27', 'CCCC' => 7, 'EXTRA' => '', ), 1 => array ( 'AAAA' => 348, 'BBBB' => 321, 'START_DATE' => '2022-07-27', 'END_DATE' => '2022-07-27', 'CCCC' => 7, 'EXTRA' => '', ), 2 => array ( 'AAAA' => 349, 'BBBB' => 321, 'START_DATE' => '2022-07-27', 'END_DATE' => '2022-07-27', 'CCCC' => 7, 'EXTRA' => '', ), 3 => array ( 'AAAA' => 350, 'BBBB' => 321, 'START_DATE' => '2022-07-27', 'END_DATE' => '2022-07-27', 'CCCC' => 7, 'EXTRA' => '', ), 4 => array ( 'AAAA' => 351, 'BBBB' => 321, 'START_DATE' => '2022-07-27', 'END_DATE' => '2022-07-27', 'CCCC' => 7, 'EXTRA' => '', ), 5 => array ( 'AAAA' => 352, 'BBBB' => 322, 'START_DATE' => '2022-07-27', 'END_DATE' => '2022-07-27', 'CCCC' => 2, 'EXTRA' => '', ), 6 => array ( 'AAAA' => 354, 'BBBB' => 323, 'START_DATE' => '2022-07-27', 'END_DATE' => '2022-07-27', 'CCCC' => 9, 'EXTRA' => '', ), 7 => array ( 'AAAA' => 355, 'BBBB' => 323, 'START_DATE' => '2022-07-27', 'END_DATE' => '2022-07-27', 'CCCC' => 9, 'EXTRA' => '', ), 8 => array ( 'AAAA' => 6, 'BBBB' => 1, 'START_DATE' => '2022-07-27', 'END_DATE' => '2022-07-27', 'CCCC' => 2, 'EXTRA' => '', ), 9 => array ( 'AAAA' => 6, 'BBBB' => 2, 'START_DATE' => '2022-07-27', 'END_DATE' => '2022-07-27', 'CCCC' => 2, 'EXTRA' => '', ), 10 => array ( 'AAAA' => 6, 'BBBB' => 3, 'START_DATE' => '2022-07-27', 'END_DATE' => '2022-07-27', 'CCCC' => 2, 'EXTRA' => '', ), 11 => array ( 'AAAA' => 6, 'BBBB' => 4, 'START_DATE' => '2022-07-27', 'END_DATE' => '2022-07-27', 'CCCC' => 2, 'EXTRA' => '', ), );
```

Just call the function.

```
$result = getData($data, ['BBBB','START_DATE','END_DATE','CCCC']);
```

And the result is:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:5 [▼
    0 => array:6 [▼
      "AAAA" => 347
      "BBBB" => 321
      "START_DATE" => "2022-07-27"
      "END_DATE" => "2022-07-27"
      "CCCC" => 7
      "EXTRA" => ""
    ]
    1 => array:6 [▼
      "AAAA" => 348
      "BBBB" => 321
      "START_DATE" => "2022-07-27"
      "END_DATE" => "2022-07-27"
      "CCCC" => 7
      "EXTRA" => ""
    ]
    2 => array:6 [▼
      "AAAA" => 349
      "BBBB" => 321
      "START_DATE" => "2022-07-27"
      "END_DATE" => "2022-07-27"
      "CCCC" => 7
      "EXTRA" => ""
    ]
    3 => array:6 [▼
      "AAAA" => 350
      "BBBB" => 321
      "START_DATE" => "2022-07-27"
      "END_DATE" => "2022-07-27"
      "CCCC" => 7
      "EXTRA" => ""
    ]
    4 => array:6 [▼
      "AAAA" => 351
      "BBBB" => 321
      "START_DATE" => "2022-07-27"
      "END_DATE" => "2022-07-27"
      "CCCC" => 7
      "EXTRA" => ""
    ]
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    0 => array:6 [▼
      "AAAA" => 354
      "BBBB" => 323
      "START_DATE" => "2022-07-27"
      "END_DATE" => "2022-07-27"
      "CCCC" => 9
      "EXTRA" => ""
    ]
    1 => array:6 [▼
      "AAAA" => 355
      "BBBB" => 323
      "START_DATE" => "2022-07-27"
      "END_DATE" => "2022-07-27"
      "CCCC" => 9
      "EXTRA" => ""
    ]
  ]
]
```

Comment: The values are dynamics. And i want to output only item that have the same (duplicate) values on keys : BBBB,START_DATE,END_DATE,CCCC.